# How to use beautifulsoup's select method to extract text without a tag

Tags: python, css, parsing, beautifulsoup

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getPage(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return None
    return BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

bs = getPage('https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-launch-probe-minneapolis-police-after-george-floyd-murder'
             '-report-2021-04-21/')
bs.select_one('div.ArticleHeader__container___3rO4Ad h1')
```

which outputs

```html
<h1 class="Text__text___3eVx1j Text__dark-grey___AS2I_p Text__medium___1ocDap 
Text__heading_2___sUlNJP Heading__base___1dDlXY Heading__heading_2___3f_bIW 
ArticleHeader__heading___3ibi0Q">
<span class="Text__text___3eVx1j Text__tr-orange___2pfU9O 
Text__bold___2wRTrQ Text__heading_5___3obGkm Heading__base___1dDlXY heading_5_bold 
ArticleHeader__section___115N2f">
<a class="Text__text___3eVx1j Text__inherit-color___30vgWE 
Text__inherit-font___34PF0W Text__inherit-size___hM-VSj Link__underline_on_hover___3-iv5a" 
href="/world/us">United States</a></span>Minneapolis police face U.S. bias probe after Floyd murder verdict</h1>
```

I want to retrieve the text in between the tags "Minneapolis police face U.S. bias probe after Floyd murder verdict", but find myself unable. I know this question might seem like a duplicate but the other threads all use the `.find()` or `.findall()` methods. Any suggestions?

Comment: it may be `find('span').tail`

Comment: @furas I have tried it and it returned `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BS you can use `find('span').next_sibling`

```
item = bs.select_one('div.ArticleHeader__container___3rO4Ad h1')

print( item.find('span').next_sibling )
```

Because it is last string in `h1` so you could use

```
print( list(item.strings)[-1] )
```

It is also last `child` in `h1`

```
print( list(item.children)[-1] )
```

and last element in `content`

```
print( item.contents[-1] )
```

---

And `.tail` you could use in `lxml`

```
item = tree.cssselect('div.ArticleHeader__container___3rO4Ad h1')[0]

print( item.find('span').tail )
```

---

BTW: if you want to list all functions then you can use `dir()`

```
print( '\n'.join(dir(item)) )  # all commands
```

or `help()` without `print()` (it can scroll up and down, and you can use `/` to search)

```
help(item)
```

Or you should read all [documentation for BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) because it gives also examples.

---

Minimal working code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html

print('--- BS ---')

def get_page(url):  # PEP8: lower_case_names
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return None
    return BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

bs = get_page('https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-launch-probe-minneapolis-police-after-george-floyd-murder'
             '-report-2021-04-21/')
             
item = bs.select_one('div.ArticleHeader__container___3rO4Ad h1')
#print(item)

print( item.find('span').next_sibling )
print( list(item.strings)[-1] )
print( list(item.children)[-1] )

#print( '\n'.join(dir(item)) )  # all commands

print('--- LXML ---')

def get_page(url):  # PEP8: lower_case_names
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return None
    return lxml.html.fromstring(req.text)

tree = get_page('https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-launch-probe-minneapolis-police-after-george-floyd-murder'
             '-report-2021-04-21/')
             
item = tree.cssselect('div.ArticleHeader__container___3rO4Ad h1')[0]

print( item.find('span').tail )
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not always be next_sibling if looking across different pages so perhaps look for something more consistent, such as the how it is listed within `script` tag, from which title is loaded. You can use regex to extract this:

```
import re

re.search(r'"headline":"(.*?)"', str(bs), flags = re.S).group(1)
```